# Is there a way in R to use column values (string) to reference row names in a separate dataframe (row names are the same as the column values)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data set of all of the matches played in the English Premier League and the results, along with stats. I am trying to build a separate dataframe to represent the league table (standings) after each week of play. I would like to use the string values from prem_results_2023$Results to reference row names in my other dataframe, LeagueTable. Then I would be able to generate point totals for each team for each week, and get a snapshot of what the league table looked like for each week when doing my analysis. Within LeagueTable, the column "Wk0" is an initialized week for the start of the season, and will remain as a zero vector always. "Wk1" then represents the point totals of teams after the first week of matches has been played. After this, if a team wins in Wk2, 3 points will be added to the value of Wk1 for that team, to keep a running total. I have omitted this from the dput for the sake of brevity though.

My goal is to do something along the lines of

```
ifelse(prem_results_2023$Result == Home, Table[Home, Wk1] = Table[Home,Wk0] +3, Table[Away, Wk1] = Table[Away, Wk0] +3)
```

but the syntax may be a bit off on this. I took a class in R in college but haven't touched it in about a year, and am trying to get back to using it for fun personal projects. I have been able to force the code to do what I want by calling cells by row and column number instead of name, but this is dependent on me knowing which team names appear on which line i.e. Arsenal wins in the first row, and Arsenal is the 15th rowname of my df Table, and I can't figure out a better way to make this cleaner. Below is a sample of 5 games from prem_results_2023, along with the desired output into LeagueTable. I have included all 20 Teams in LeagueTable for the sake of clarity.

```
structure(list(Season_End_Year = c(2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 
2023L), Home = c("Crystal Palace", "Fulham", "Tottenham", "Newcastle Utd", 
"Leeds United"), HomeGoals = c(0, 2, 4, 2, 2), Home_xG = c(1.2, 
1.2, 1.5, 1.7, 0.8), Away = c("Arsenal", "Liverpool", "Southampton", 
"Nott'ham Forest", "Wolves"), AwayGoals = c(2, 2, 1, 0, 1), Away_xG = c(1, 
1.2, 0.5, 0.3, 1.3), Referee = c("Anthony Taylor", "Andy Madley", 
"Andre Marriner", "Simon Hooper", "Robert Jones"), Goal_Diff = c(-2, 
0, 3, 2, 1), Result = c("Arsenal", "Draw", "Tottenham", "Newcastle Utd", 
"Leeds United")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
structure(list(Team = c("Crystal Palace", "Fulham", "Tottenham", 
"Newcastle Utd", "Leeds United", "Bournemouth", "Everton", "Leicester City", 
"Manchester Utd", "West Ham", "Aston Villa", "Manchester City", 
"Southampton", "Wolves", "Arsenal", "Brighton", "Brentford", 
"Nott'ham Forest", "Chelsea", "Liverpool"), Wk0 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Wk1 = c(0, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
if(prem_results_2023[1,10] == "Arsenal") Table[15, 3] = Table[15, 2] + 3
```

Comment: Welcome! A few suggestions: (a) Please share a little bit of data in a reproducible way. `dput(prem_results_2023[1:5, ])` will make copy/pasteable R code to create the first 5 rows of `prem_results_2023` that anyone can use without installing any packages. (b) After using `dput` to share a little bit of `prem_results_2023` and `Table`, you can focus your question more directly on the issue by deleting the code needed to create/transform these objects, and (c) please show the desired result for the sample input so we can test solutions and know if they are correct.

Comment: One last general point, please don't include `rm(list=ls())` in your sample code unless it is a crucial part of your question. No one wants to inadvertently run that line and lose whatever they were working on.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I have just updated the question with the dput outputs (I hope I did it correctly). The bottom line of code forces the result I want for Table,  ("Arsenal" appears in prem_results_2023[1,10] which corresponds to the Results column, so 3 points are added to Wk0 value to get the Wk1 value), and this would ideally happen for each team in each round. grouping by round or including an if statement for if prem_results_2023$Round == i might be necessary at some point

Comment: The `dput` looks great, thank you! However I'm still confused about the desired result. From the `dput` you shared, `prem_results_2023[1,10]` is Crystal Palace, not Arsenal. I think things would be clearer if (a) you described more in words what your goal is--does the `Round` column in `prem_results` correspond to the `Wk` value of `Table`? Or are you just trying to add 3 to `Wk0` every time a team shows up in the `Result` column. No additions if the result is a draw?

Comment: I would recommend shrinking the sample input to simplify the problem--5 rows is probably plenty--and then explicitly show what the whole result should look like for those 5 rows. If we can both see the result, and you explain the result, that usually makes things very clear.

Comment: Mr. Thomas, thank you again for your feedback. I have made some updates to the question to hopefully provide more clarity. Draws will be included in this table, I had omitted them from the initial question for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Thank you for being responsive to feedback! I think that there is probably a way to construct your filled-in Table directly from `prem_results_2023`, probably by pivoting the data and doing a sum. This will be much more efficient and generalizable than the fill-in-the-rows-one-at-a-time method you've begun. This is why it would be nice to see the desired result. (And for that we don't need a `dput()` because we don't need to use it as input. Just a few rows in a table format would be great.)

Comment: For terminology's sake, I'd also note that neither of your tables have defined Row Names. You can see in the `dput`, they both have `row.names = c(NA...`. This is good--row names are not reliable in R and should generally be avoided. But rather than "row names" you should be thinking of "the value in the Team column".

Comment: Oh, oops. I had previously made the row name the same as the team names, but forgot I had commented that line out in my code yesterday. Looks like it was a happy accident though!